# Get feedback on review result

Tags: feature-request, review

In the (new) review system a 'Not Sure' button is available when the reviewer does not know whether the change is correct or not.

In order to let the reviewer learn about show to handle this review request, it would be nice to get/provide feedback on the review request where the reviewer choose 'Not Sure'.
So the reviewer able is learn about the (community) decisions and might know what to choose a next time.

On the [review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) an additional link could be added to a new page showing the results (and explanations) of the review requests where the user choose 'Not Sure'.

Comment: It's an interesting idea.  A list of links to the review pages would suffice.